# Deep Learning: глибинне чи глибоке навчання?

Tags: переклад, терміни, прикметники

Deep Learning — галузь машинного навчання (machine learning), що використовує багатошарові штучні нейронні мережі для розв'язання різних задач - від класифікації до машинного перекладу.

Стаття у Вікіпедії перекладає `deep learning` як `глибинне навчання`, однак зустрічається і варіант `глибоке навчання`.

Який варіант є правильним?

Answer (score 7):

Навчання не проходить "на глибині", а йде повністю, з поверхні до найглибшого місця.  Наприклад, **глибинна** бомба вибухає на певному шарі, на певній глибині. А навчання **глибоке**, бо навчання відбувається скрізь. А не лише на глибинних шарах. Більше того, в англійській learning is deep, тому що мережа - глибока.

Ось, наприклад, цитата з  Deep Learning Book by Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville
https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/intro.html

> The hierarchy of concepts enables the computer to learn complicated
> concepts by building them out of simpler ones. If we draw a graph
> showing how these concepts are built on top of each other, the graph
> is deep, with many layers. For this reason, we call this approach to
> AI deep learning

Крім того, є протиставлення shallow learning vs deep learning. Це протиставлення встрачається при перекладі "глибинний", натомість з'являється додатковий сенс, якого не було. Приклад: кажуть про "глибинний зміст", мова йде про неочевидний зміст, захований на глибині, а не лежить на поверхні. В нейромережах, у свою чергу, зміст розподілений по всіх шарах, а не десь на певній глибині.

Comment: Отже, тоді *shallow learning* — *неглибоке (мілинне?) навчання*, а не *поверхневе*?

Comment: *Більше того, в англійській learning is deep, тому що мережа - глибока.* Глибинне теж перекладається як deep, тому цей аргумент недоречний.

Comment: Якщо в мережі 10 шарів і всі після 2-го ми вважаємо глибокими, то навчання відбувається переважно на глибині і тому термін *глибинне* підходить.

Answer (score 3):

Почну з того, що із [Вікіпедією](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) в цьому питанні буде складно сперечатися. Це ресурс, який з'являється в ґуґлі першим на запит deep learning, і цю статтю переглядає [досить багато](https://pageviews.toolforge.org/?project=uk.wikipedia.org&platform=all-access&agent=all-agents&redirects=0&range=latest-90&pages=%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) людей. Та перейдімо до доступних методів аналізу.

#### ГРАК

Корпус не допомагає: три результати за запитом "[глибинне навчання](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&reload=&iquery=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&queryselector=iqueryrow&lemma=&phrase=&word=&char=&cql=&default_attr=word&fc_lemword_window_type=both&fc_lemword_wsize=5&fc_lemword=&fc_lemword_type=all&usesubcorp=&fsca_doc.author=&fsca_doc.translator=&fsca_doc.authTrans=&fsca_doc.born=&fsca_doc.title=&fsca_doc.date=&fsca_doc.mediaName=&fsca_doc.locCode=&fsca_doc.region=&fsca_doc.publicationCity=&fsca_doc.publisher=&fsca_doc.publication=&fsca_doc.uri=)" й ті самі три результати за запитом "[глибоке навчання](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&corpname=grac10&corpus-search-form=true)". Ці результати немає сенсу аналізувати й порівнювати, бо це навіть близько не узус і не вибірка.

#### GOOGLE

Доведеться звернутися до менш надійного Google. Знову маємо приблизно однакові результати: [12 сторінок](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk033X0yil8b5rpTybYhOrrDmfIrVxQ:1615639027895&ei=87FMYOWZNqnnrgSWy4SgBA&start=110&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwil396ypK3vAhWps4sKHZYlAUQ4WhDy0wN6BAgEEEs&biw=1472&bih=715) результатів на запит "глибинне навчання" й [14 сторінок](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk005ZXravZY7eJZr_RHXqIbfm2GYsg:1615639037134&ei=_bFMYKDfB-mgrgTp54qYAw&start=130&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjg0ZK3pK3vAhVpkIsKHemzAjM4WhDy0wN6BAgEEEs&biw=1472&bih=715) результатів за запитом "глибоке навчання". Спробую порівняти джерела на перших двох сторінках.

За глибинне навчання: Вікіпедія, [онлайн-курси Prometheus](https://courses.prometheus.org.ua/courses/course-v1:UQ+DLTP101+2018_T3/about), [КУБГ](https://sites.google.com/a/kubg.edu.ua/integrovani-sistemi/masinne-navcanna-machine-learning-glibinne-navcanna-deep-learning/vvedenna-u-glibinne-navcanna), [ВНТУ](http://ir.lib.vntu.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/22575/98.%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%96%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD.%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B0.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), [КШЕ](https://kse.ua/ua/kse-course/glibinne-navchannya/), [ХДМА](https://rep.ksma.ks.ua/jspui/bitstream/123456789/196/1/Kudryavtseva_deeper.pdf), [онлайн-курси ED-ERA](https://courses.ed-era.com/courses/course-v1:British_Council+BC1+2020/about), [Віртуальний центр цифрової науки](http://cloud-5.bitp.kiev.ua/?page_id=450), [словник glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/uk/en/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), [Запорізька Політехника](https://zp.edu.ua/sites/default/files/konf/gnzkgd.pdf), [Британська рада](https://www.britishcouncil.org.ua/sites/default/files/programa_klyuchovi_uminnya_21-go_stolittya.pdf), [ЗНУ](https://moodle.znu.edu.ua/course/view.php?id=9295) тощо.

За глибоке навчання: видавництво [Пітер Прес](https://balka-book.com/ua/iskusstvennyiy_intelekt_neyronnyie_seti-19/glubokoe_obuchenie-58993), [Научний журнал Интернаука](https://www.inter-nauka.com/issues/2018/11/3951), сайт [evergreens.com.ua](https://evergreens.com.ua/ua/articles/neural-network.html), [НУ"ЛП"](http://science.lpnu.ua/sites/default/files/journal-paper/2020/feb/21058/var1ksm-19-99-104.pdf) і ще декілька неясних видань.

Хоч я і поважаю Львівську політехніку, але тут вона, очевидно, в меншості. Можна зробити висновок, що в науковому узусі більше прижилося "глибинне навчання", а в загальному узусі використовуються обидва словосполучення, хоч Вікіпедія перехиляє його в бік "глибинного навчання". Якби я станом на зараз обирав, яке використовувати словосполучення, я би обрав **глибинне навчання**.

#### Словник

Словник не допомагає. Глибинний і глибокий часто мають взаємозамінні значення. Не можна чітко сказати, яке з них більше пасує. Орієнтуватися таки доведеться на узус. З іншого боку, у визначенні deep learning йдеться про шари, і слово "[глибинний](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghlybynnyj)" використовується поруч із "шарами" в інших контекстах:

> Знання будови **глибинних шарів** Землі допомагає вивчати розміщення різних мінеральних корисних копалин в її надрах (Наука і життя, 1, 1957, 22);

Думаю, всі факти свідчать на користь **"глибинного навчання"**.

Comment: Як практик, категорично не згоден.

https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6621/3501

Comment: @old-ufo семантично погоджуюся. Словотворчо - не дуже. Іноді приживається не дуже точний варіант. Сподіваюсь, у нас приживеться точний, але мовні закони цього не передбачають. Тобто, або цим хтось дуже ґрунтовно займеться, або випадково на популярних ресурсах щось зміниться, тоді є шанс. Інакше - ні.

Answer (score 2):

## Витяги

Олекса Синявський, 1941

Норми української літературної мови → Словотвір → Наростки прикметникові

> [§ 100. Значіння їх і вживання](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky)
>
> 27. **-кий** (**-окий**) — дуже поширений наросток при інших наростках (**-ський**, **-енький**…), але й сам буває при деяких пнях:
>
>     а) при іменникових пнях: *соло́дкий, швидки́й, струнки́й, шорстки́й, боязки́й, пухки́й*…, де подекуди він уже не відчувається як наросток, надто в **-окий**: *широкий, глибокий, високий*…
>
> 31. **-ний**, **-ній** — найширше вживаний наросток при різних пнях і з різноманітним значінням:
>
>     а) при іменникових пнях на означення *матеріялу*, далі *відношення*, *ґатунку*, *властивости* (але в меншій мірі, як **-астий**, **-истий**): *молочний, пшеничний, залізний, камінний, мідний, розумний, бездоганний, срібний, житній, оксамитний, будівельний, народній, барвний*… (отже наближається значінням, а іноді й спадається з **-овий**, **-яний**).

## Висновок

Якшчо *грубо* і не забувати про *переважно*, то:

- *Глибокий* просто позначає прикметність до *глибу*, в тому числі *глиб-ини*. Тобто „подібний” глибині.
- *Глибинний* позначає те саме, але радше зі властивостями. Тобто „шчось є са́мою” глибиною.

Можна підставяти слова як *низький* проти *низинний* і *рівень*, аби легше сприйняти.

Як розумію, тут *deep* наведене як подібність чи мету, тому надаю перевагу на користь **глибокий**.

Answer (score 2):

Для правильного перекладу треба розуміти який сенс вкладено у англійське слово **deep** в оригінальному терміні. Наскільки я розумію, **deep** використовується для позначення розміру мережі, тобто на мою думку **глибокий** буде більш правильно, оскільки це слово може використовуватися як характеристика розміру. Натомість **глибинний** не має такого значення, тому досить дивно чому саме його було обрано як основний варіант перекладу.